# Convert Map to JsonParser using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I would like to take advantage of the JsonParser API class of the Jackson library.  However, it is quite tedious for me to build a json string builder.  So I made use of a Map to contain the values for my Json object.

```
   Map<String,Object> myMainMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
   Map<String,String> myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
   myMap.put("node1","value1");
   myMap.put("node2","value2");
   myMainMap.put("rootNode",myMap);
```

How do I convert this Map into a org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser so that I can take advantage of the methods available for this API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(myMap) );
```

Comment: Thanks Sandeep. I was able to use what you gave and then did this:
    JsonParser jParser = new ObjectMapper().getJsonFactory().createJsonParser(mapper.writeValueAsString(myMap));