# jQuery : How can I iterate over Java HashMap<Long,String> into Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hashmap

I am returning `HashMap<Long,String>` from server on one of the Ajax calls. How can I iterate over the it to extract key,value pair?

Thank you

Comment: What does the response look like on the client?

Comment: Can you post the returned (I guess) `JSON` ?

Comment: Convert the Map to JSON with Jackson: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11136376/convert-map-to-jsonparser-using-jackson

Answer (score 1):

Return it as JSON object:

```
{1:"String",5:"Foo"}
```

On the client, you can then access the elements then using `data[1]` and `data[5]`. While it looks like an array access, JavaScript will do the right thing (Kudos to [Felix Kling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) for pointing that out).

Comment: *"Note that you can't use numbers as JavaScript object keys"* That's incorrect. Example: `var obj = {5: 'foo'};`. It's true that the property has to be accessed with `obj[5]`, but that's not "array access", it's called *bracket notation* and is just an alternative way to access properties. See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators). In fact, arrays are just objects themselves and each element of the array is a property (with a numeric property name) of that underlying object.

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks, fixed. I should really write more code :-)

Comment: Thank you guys it is returned as object hash(associative array) and I was able to retrieve values through simple for loop.